# Custom Resolution For vt Console in FreeBSD 10

Tags: freebsd, monitors, edid

In FreeBSD 10 there is new vt driver for having nice framebuffer console. By default it chooses resolution from the EDID data of monitor. However, I have a display that has incorrect EDID data. Therefore, I get the wrong resolution.

How can I specify custom resolution for vt framebuffer console to get this display working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the `kern.vt.fb.default_mode` sysctl. See the [vt man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vt&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011-current&arch=default&format=html) for more details.

Comment: Seems this is only available in 11-CURRENT, not 10.1-RELEASE.

Comment: I have both `kern.vt.fb.default_mode="1280x768"` and `efi_max_resolution="1280x768"` in my loader.conf but still, it boots in VGA: 640x480